# PL/SQL functions with one parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was wondering if you could help.

I'm at my wits end with this.

I want to create a function that will take one parameter.

Here is my code. I keep getting the error when run:

> Error(3,19): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of thefollowing:
>   begin function pragma procedure subtype type   current cursor delete exists prior external language

Code

```
set serveroutput on;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CheckBookType (
  p_book_type  TITLES.CATEGORY
) RETURN BOOLAN IS;

BEGIN

  IF (p_book_type = 'business') THEN


    return true;

  ELSE

   return false;

  END IF;

  RETURN v_ReturnValue;
END CheckBookType;
```

Comment: You have multiple issues with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Least verbose solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CheckBookType (
        p_book_type IN  TITLES.CATEGORY%type
    ) RETURN BOOLEAN 
IS
BEGIN

  return p_book_type = 'business';

END CheckBookType;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the issues line by line in your code :

> set serveroutput on;

1. It doesn't make any harm, but I don't see how it helps or is required in the context.
2. `p_book_type  TITLES.CATEGORY` is wrong, since you need to specify that it is a `constrained` data type using the `%TYPE attribute`. The correct way is

`p_book_type  TITLES.CATEGORY%TYPE`

3. Already mentioned above by others, the datatype of return value should be `BOOLEAN`. and you don't have to put semi-colon after "IS".
4. The `variable` to return the boolean value is NOT declared.

`v_ReturnValue BOOLEAN;`

5. Remember, **using `BOOLEAN` data type as return will NOT let you use the `function` in `SQL`**. Since, boolean is NOT a SQL data type. Boolean is `PL/SQL` data type. You could only use the function in PL/SQL and NOT in SQL.

Your function would look like :

Quite verbose.

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION Checkbooktype (p_book_type titles.category%TYPE) 
RETURN BOOLEAN 
IS 
  v_returnvalue BOOLEAN; 
BEGIN 
    IF ( p_book_type = 'business' ) THEN 
      v_returnvalue:= TRUE; 
    ELSE 
      v_returnvalue:= FALSE; 
    END IF; 

    RETURN v_returnvalue; 
END checkbooktype; 

/
```

Or, without and `ELSE`, taking return default as `FALSE`.

Less verbose.

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION Checkbooktype (p_book_type titles.category%TYPE) 
RETURN BOOLEAN 
IS 
  v_returnvalue BOOLEAN; 
BEGIN 

    v_returnvalue:= FALSE;

    IF ( p_book_type = 'business' ) THEN 
      v_returnvalue:= TRUE;  
    END IF; 

    RETURN v_returnvalue; 
END checkbooktype; 

/
```

@APC's solution is least verbose.

Comment: Even your answer is not correct.  The IF/ELSE branches execute RETURN calls so the final call is never executed.  Hence the variable declaration is irrelevant.

Comment: @APC, correct. I just copy pasted the IF-ELSE block. In fact the conditional construct is not at all required. I see you already posted it, so I would edit my answer in other way.